# Why does ignore() before getline() take one less character input?

Tags: c++

I am using the `getline()` function in C++, but there is a problem that the input starts from the second character. I used the `ignore()` function to erase what remains in the buffer first, emptying the buffer and receiving input. How can I empty the buffer and receive input properly?

[image]

Above is the execution result. I previously used the `ignore()` function and the `getline()` function to empty the buffer and receive input because there may be some leftovers in the buffer before.

In other programs that write like that, it also receives integer input before.

```
void InputValue(string *st) {
    //cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, *st);
}

int main(void) {
    string str;
    InputValue(&str);

    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What happened when you did that? What is the output of your code? Is there any error? What kind of? I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: Why did you put the `cin.ignore()` there in the first place? What problem were you hoping/told it would solve in *this* code? And fyi, `ignore()` (no arguments) doesn't "erase what remains in the buffer first". It consumes and discards *one* character from the input stream.

Comment: You can see instructions and examples in [std::istream::ignore](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: As for your problem, when you start your program there will be nothing in any buffers. Your program starts from a clean slate, and there's no previous input.

Comment: "*I previously used the `ignore()` function ... because there may be some leftovers in the buffer before*" - then you should call `ignore()` immediately after the operation that left the unwanted data in the buffer, not before the next operation that wants to read from the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning, immediately after input, `stdin` (your input buffer) contains :

```
abcd
```

Those character are waiting to be extracted in whatever manner you choose. Since you are reading from `stdin` (using `std::cin`) using `getline()` from the stream into a `std::string`, `getline()` will consume all characters in the line, reading and discarding the trailing `'\n'` with all characters stored in your `std::string`. There are no characters left in `stdin` that need to be extracted using `std::cin.ignore()`

When you call `std::cin.ignore()` **before** `getline()` you are reading (and discarding) the first character waiting to be read in `stdin`. With the example characters above, after calling `std::cin.ignore()`, and extracting and discarding the character, the following is left in `stdin`:

```
bcd
```

So now when you do call `getline (std::cin, *st);` `"bcd"` are the only characters that are available. That is the reason why you miss the first character.

While you can `std::cin.ignore()` one character, the `.ignore()` member function is usually used to read/discard all remaining characters in a line using the form

```cpp
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Where `#include <limits>` provides the constants representing the maximum number of the type specified, above `<std::streamsize>::max()` (e.g. the maximum value that `size_t` can represent). A large constant is used to ensure the remainder of the line, no matter how long, is consumed and discarded leaving `std::cin` either empty or with the first character of the next line (in a multi-line buffer) waiting to be read.

[std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) can also read up to a delimiter character reading/discarding less than the whole line. That can be useful when reading separated fields, or in cases where you use a delimiter with `getline()` to read less than an entire line.

You either perform your read operation first and then call `ignore()` to discard unwanted characters to the end of the line, or you can call `ignore()` first with either a specified number of characters (default `1`) or a delimiter to discard the beginning portion of a line up to the first character you want to began your read with.

As you have used it above, it will simply chop off the first character of whatever the user enters -- which does not seem to be what you want. In fact, `ignore()` isn't even needed above. Remove it and see if the missing character problem doesn't go away.